# What is correct sentence to ask, How much money or how many money?

Tags: singular-vs-plural, sentence-choice

What is correct sentence to ask,

- How much money
- How many money
- How many dollars

In case of singular noun we use much, but is money singular?
I'm a bit confused need help here.

Comment: The **word** "money" is uncountable.  Specific examples of money, like "dollars", are countable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A dollar is a unit of money, so it is a countable noun. So you would say

> How *many* dollars?

not

> How *much* dollars?

*Money*, is not a countable noun. It refers to all types of money and money in general. Therefore, you would say:

> How *much* money?

Instead of

> How many money?